# How to Expose Listbox in UserControl in CustomTaskPane VSTO C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am creating an application level add-in for Word 2010 using C# VSTO. I created a User Control, placed controls within it, and then used the User Control to add a Custom Task Pane:

```
UserControl myUserControl;
myUserControl = new PageElementsPane();
mytaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add
    (myUserControl, "Page Elements", doc.ActiveWindow);
```

So far so good. However, the User Control contains a listbox that I have not been able to access after the Custom Task Pane is added to the Custom Task Pane collection.

I have tried setting the Modifiers property on the listbox to Public. I have tried exposing the listbox on the User Control as a Public Property:

```
 public partial class PageElementsPane: UserControl
 {
    public ListBox ElementsPaneListBox
    {
        get { return lbxListbox; }
    }
 }
```

Additionally, I looked at this SO post:

[Working with ListBox elements in a user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695909/working-with-listbox-elements-in-a-user-control)

I hoped I could adapt it, but my listbox IntelliSense does not have `FindControl`, offering `FindForm` instead. Is there a way to access the listbox within the User Control by somehow interpreting the Custom Task Pane as a form? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code do you use for accessing the list box control? Do you cast the user control to the actual type (`PageElementsPane`) to access the public members?

Comment: Thank you @EugeneAstafiev! Upon reading your comment I looked at the casting again and did some additional research. I was type `UserControl` instead of `Control`. I will write up a more detailed answer after leaving this comment and post below. Very much appreciate the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears my `foreach` (and hence my cast) was not correct (per Eugene Astafiev's question in the comment above). I found this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223451/casting-new-system-windows-forms-control-object-to-system-windows-forms-textbox) that suggesting looping with type `Control` instead of `UserControl`. I did this and all was good. Here is the code:

```
foreach (Control lbxControl in myUserControl.Controls)
{
    if (lbxControl is ListBox)
    {
        ((ListBox)lbxControl).SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```